# id is not passing to the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my categories to show in my **Post Controller Show Action**. 
In my Post Association I have

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :categorie
end
```

And in my Categorie:

```
class Categorie < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
end
```

And I have the follwoing code in my Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
    @cat = Categorie.all
end

def create
     @post = Post.new(post_params) 
     @cat = @post.categorie_id

     if (@post) .save
         redirect_to(:action => 'index')
     else
         render('new')
     end
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)

        redirect_to @post

        else

         render('edit')
    end

end

def delete
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

end
And in my Catrgories Controller I have

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def index
@categorie = Categorie.all
end

def show
@categorie = Categorie.find(params[:id])
@title = @categorie.title
@post = @categorie.posts
end
end
```

I have this code in my **post controller Create action**

```
<%= f.collection_select :categorie_id, @cat, :id, :title, :prompt => 'Select One' %>
```

And I have this in my **Post Controller Show Action**

```
<p>Categoriey : <strong><%=@post.categorie.title %></strong></p>
    <p>Submitted <%# time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago.</p>
```

The categorie ID is not showing.
Thanks for the Help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I believe `categorie_id` isn't saving at all because you are doing it wrong. Normally [***`collection_select`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) will accept `collection` as a ***third parameter***, so `@cat` should be replaced with `Categorie.all` or its equivalent which returns a ***collection of records***.

```
<%= f.collection_select :categorie_id, Categorie.all, :id, :title, :prompt => 'Select One' %>
```

Also, you should ***whitelist*** `categorie_id` in the `post_params` as well.

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :categorie_id)
end
```

Now `<%= @post.categorie.title %>` should give you the ***categorie title*** of that ***post***.

Comment: Thanks Pavan it works. Id is passing to the show action and the catrgorie is showing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to permit the `categorie_id` parameter by changing the following line:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
```

To:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :categorie_id)
```

Comment: Ya thanks, Eirikir. It works fine now, It is a dumb mistake that I forget to add the categorie_id to private method. Thanks again you saved my time much.